# Angular: Error after concat angular js files into single js file with gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-concat

Im using `gulp-concat` to merge all angular js files into one but after running `gulp task` i get this error in chrome console on runing application :

```
angular.js:13708Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?p0=userboxController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

my gulp task :

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  return gulp.src(['js/app/*.js', 'components/*/*/*.js'])  
    .pipe(concat('appscript.js'))
    .pipe(minify()) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
});
```

and `gulp-concat`  merges dedicated angular js files into `appscript.js` like:

```
angular.module('app',[]);     


angular
    .module("app", [])
    .controller("paymentCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('data/payments.json').then(function (payments) {
            $scope.payments = payments.data;
        });

        $scope.saveEntity = function () {
            console.info("goog");
        }
    }]); 

angular
    .module("app",[])
    .controller("userboxController", ['$scope', '$http',function ($scope, $http, usersService) {
        usersService.getCurrentUser().then(function (user) {
            $scope.user = user.data;
        });
    }]);


angular
    .module("app",[])
    .controller("usersController",['$scope', '$http','usersService', function ($scope, $http, usersService) {
        usersService.getAll().then(function (users) {
            $scope.users = users.data;
        });
    }]); 


angular
    .module("app", [])
    .directive('usersGrid', function () {
        return {
             templateUrl : 'components/users/template/grid.html'
        }
    });
```

what's wrong with angular?!!

Comment: I think something is wrong with merged js order or injections in angular, maybe!

Comment: Why don't you just do `var app = angular.module('app',[]);` and `app.controller("paymentCtrl", ...` instead?

Comment: @Arg0n it is ok , i edited appscript.js manually to use `var app = angular.module('app',[]);` and worked but   my controllers and services,.. are in dedicated .js files, and must add `var app = angular.module('app',[]); ` to all of them, how to solve this redundancy?

Comment: If i remove `var app = angular.module('app',[]);` from all JS files but app.js to avoid redundancy(i have error adding `var app = angular.module('app',[]);` in every js file )  my problem will be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a merge related problem.

You are making app modules every time with

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

You have to initialise module only one place and you will be using same module every time with ~ [] brackets.

Please find the plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/A7AiTiqvw66T4NSwHHbz?p=preview)

```
var myApp = angular.module('app');

myApp.controller("paymentCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data/payments.json').then(function(payments) {
    $scope.payments = payments.data;
  });

  $scope.saveEntity = function() {
    console.info("goog");
  }
}]);

myApp.controller("userboxController", ['$scope', '$http',       function($scope, $http, usersService) {
  $scope.user = 'abc';

}]);


myApp.controller("usersController", ['$scope', '$http', 'usersService', function($scope, $http, usersService) {
  usersService.getAll().then(function(users) {
    $scope.users = users.data;
  });
}]);


myApp.directive('usersGrid', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'components/users/template/grid.html'
  }
});
```

Comment: YEP, it  worked :), but i had error removing [] from `var myApp = angular.module('app',[])` .I have [] in `var myApp = angular.module('app')`. i dont know why!